# How can I extract text from HTML using c++?

Tags: c++, html

How can I parse HTML tags using c++?

eg:

```
<html><body>examlpe text </body></html>
```

Comment: If this is an exercise, you're better off by starting with XHTML input. It's similar enough for learning purposes, but much better structured. E.g. there are no unmatched `<br>` tags in XHTML.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest option would be to use an HTML parsing library. [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) is a solid open-source one, although it's technically a C library. You'd need to load your html and then walk through the DOM pulling out all the text() nodes. I don't know that I'd recommend this as your first C++ task.

Comment: They have a tutorial at http://www.xmlsoft.org/tutorial/ar01s05.html.

You could also just count the <> characters and extract everything that's not inside a tag. If this is a homework problem, that's probably the solution they are looking for. I'm not going to write it for you.