# Optimizing Regular Expression

Tags: regex, pcre

I have one regular expression which convert html to txt. 
But It is taking a lot of CPU usages . 
How can I optimize it ?

```
((\n|\r){2,}) | (\r|\n)|<head.*?</head>|<script.*?</script> |<meta[^>]+>|<style.*?</style> | <[^>]*> |&[^\s]*;
```

Comment: Use a parser instead of a regex.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags :)

Comment: I think CPU hike will be more with parser ?

Comment: You really think CPU usage will be high with an HTML parser, @Vivek? Do you notice high CPU usage from your Web browser while *it's* parsing the pages you download?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy . I am writing C++ application. I don't care about dom. So I think using parser will be more cpu high thing. As I only need to strip all html tags and extract text.

Comment: @Vivek, The thing to do, when there's a question of speed, is to _measure_.  Feed your page to a parser and see how long it takes compared to your regular expression.  One quick experiment would settle the matter.

Comment: @Vivek, Web browsers don't use the DOM to process the text they download. They *generate* the DOM by *parsing* the HTML text. And if you wanted to extract text from HTML, then you should have just asked [how to extract text from HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605592/how-can-i-extract-text-from-html-using-c).

Comment: @Rob Kennedy. 
I will try with libxml.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy I tried with libxml. 
It is taking 10 ms to convert html to text. 
While pcre regular expression is taking only 1 sec.

Comment: That's terrific, @Vivek! You can now process 100 files in the time it used to take you to process just one.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy 
Oh sorry I had given you wrong time for pcre. It was 1 ms not 1 sec. :(

Comment: @Goel, yeah but your regex is broken and will not work properly for a lot of valid html.

Comment: @Qtax that is acceptable case. If it works for 80% cases. 
Do you have any suggestion for parsing html ? I was not able to parse malformed html using libxml .

Answer (score 1):

Use an HTML parser if you can. Regex is bad for HTML for various reasons, and performance will inevitably suffer as well.

Comment: Error recovery is challenging in parsers. The only times regexes work well for HTML is when it is **not** general open‐ended HTML, but rather well‐defined HTML snippets. Even then, use [grammatical regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840988/the-recognizing-power-of-modern-regexes/4843579#4843579), not compact ones. The **very best regex approaches** themselves strongly resemble actual lexers, such as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491). I’d stick to existing parsing modules if possible.

Comment: @Francies Glibert. 
I am not able to find parser which can parse malformed html. 
I see one discussion going on SL but that tell to pase html to first tidy. and than libxml. 
That will be more resource hungry for me . 
As I don't care about valid html . I just need to extract text part.